# UIImagepicker works for camera but not for photo album

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have the following code to let the user take a photo or select from the album.  While taking the picture from the camera works perfect, when I choose the button that triggers the action to choose from an album the album comes up but you cant actually select a photo.  I do get a warning in the console when launching the choose from album method that I do not get when I launch the take from camera method.  Below is the relvant code and warning.

.h

```
@interface sitespecTakePhoto : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,                       UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pbvlocname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *successLabel;
@property UIImage *imageToSend;
@property NSString *desc;
- (IBAction)imageFromCamera:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)resignKeyboard:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)uploadButtonClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)imageFromCamera:(id)sender
{

imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)imageFromAlbum:(id)sender
{
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Delegate Methods

//  Dismiss the image picker on selection and use the resulting image in our ImageView
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:    (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

[[imagePicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[imageField setImage:image];
imageToSend = image;



}

//  On cancel, only dismiss the picker controller
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[[imagePicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES   completion:nil];
}


 - (IBAction)resignKeyboard:(id)sender
{
desc = descTextField.text;
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and the warning I get when I press the button to fire the imageFromAlbum method:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x1d59d6b0> on <UINavigationController: 0x1e0319f0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Again, the album is shown but nothing happens when you tap an image or press the cancel button, it almost seems to me this method is not recognizing the UIImagePicker delegate methods whereas the imageFromCamera method is.  THanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How do you let the choose between camera or photo album? Action sheet? Which delegate method do you use?

Comment: imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:Deprecated. Use imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key phrase in the error message is "while a presentation is in progress". This suggests that you are doing this at a time when another `presentViewController` is firing. My bet is that you've accidentally hooked this button to *two* methods so that it is trying to execute two `presentViewController` commands simultaneously. Use the connections inspector at the right of the Interface Builder to straighten this out.

Comment: That was exactly it!  when I created the button to attach to the fromAlbum method, I just used Command-D to copy the other button that I had already connected to the fromCamera method!    Thanks so much, excuse me now while I hang my head in shame :-)

Comment: But how do you think I was able to guess the source of the problem? Because I've done *exactly* the same thing! The ability of a control action message to have multiple targets is sort of surprising, and Command-D is the easiest way to get surprised by it.